# Spring @Transactional inheritance behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have the following structure:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<E, K extends Serializable, R extends BaseRepository<E, K>> implements BaseService<E, K> {

    protected BaseServiceImpl(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public E save(E entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> saveAll(List<E> entities) {
        return repository.saveAll(entities);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> findByKey(K entityKey) {
        if (entityKey != null) {
            return repository.findById(entityKey);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> search(String filter, Integer page, Integer limit, String orderBy) {
        return repository.findAll(filter, page, limit, orderBy);
    }

    @Override
    public E update(E entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(E entity) {
        repository.delete(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteByKey(K entityKey) {
        repository.deleteById(entityKey);
    }

    @Override
    public Long count() {
        return repository.count();
    }
}


@Service
public class CustomerService extends BaseServiceImpl<CustomerEntity, String, CustomerRepository> {

    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }
}
```

The question is: will all the methods of CustomerService inherit @Transactional and behave inside transactional context?
Also I know that [Spring doc recommends to put @Transactional on specific classes or methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html), but I'm interested in the best way to avoid code duplication using @Transactional within class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

`@Transactional` annotation itself is annotated with the `@Inherited` annotation, which means that if you put it on a base class, such as `BaseServiceImpl` in your example, it will be propagated to the subclasses, `CustomerService` for you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html

It will behave exactly as if you annotated `CustomerService` directly.

As you noticed yourself, it is adviced to put `@Transactional` on a more granular level, such as methods.

Take into consideration that as your project evolves, you may not want the `@Transactional` annotations on every method and decision to annotate the base class early on may require future changes.

Also, take into consideration that it may be more difficult to maintain as usage of `@Transactional` may not be as visible for future maintainers as it will be kind of hidden behind the base class.

Take the pros a cons into consideration and choose whatever is most suitable for you.

Comment: From the doc you provided:
"Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class." So if I put Transactional on methods in BaseServiceImpl. Does this mean that Transactional won't be inherited on methods level in CustomerService? Thanks.

Comment: You're correct. Putting @Transactional on a method in the base class won't have any effect on the overridden method in the child class

Answer (score 1):

`@Transactional` on a class level will be applied to every `public` method. `private` and `protected` methods will be ignored.

But what you are doing is really not good practice. For read-only operation (e.g getting from the database), you should use `@Transactional(readonly = true)` because it has optimizations compared to only `@Transactional`.

Therefore, I suggest not worrying about duplications and just put the annotation where you need it.

Extra: Be aware that calling method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` from another `@Transactional` method within the same bean will not create new transaction due to Spring proxy behavior.

Comment: Ok, but if I make more precise annotating: put @Transactional with suitable propagation on each method inside BaseService. Will this bevahior still be inhertied in CustomerService?

Another question: what is more suitable for readOnly operations: @Transactional(SUPPORTS) or @Transactional(readOnly=true)?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `@Transactional(readonly=true)` as per documentation: just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it will not necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction.

`@Transactional(SUPPORTS)` is totally different - you are giving propagation type to define how the method's transaction will behave. `SUPPORTS` supports the current transaction and execute non-transactionally if none exists.

Comment: Yes, that's all correct, I might didn't ask the question correctly: I've read an opinion that starting a new transaction is a costly operation (which is true) thus it's better to use @Transaction(SUPPORTS) on readOnly operation, this way readOnly operations will run without any transaction if there were none. On the other hand there is @Transactional(readOnly=true).  I'm just curios what is considered to be a best practice.

Comment: I think that all depends on your needs and the nature of the method. Spring's CRUD repository will anyway open a new transaction with the REQUIRED propagation type, even if you don't annotate your method with @Transactional. I would personally always use @Transactional(readOnly = true) with the default propagation REQUIRED since Spring will anyway do it and you can just optimize it more with 'readOnly'. I hope we are on the same page